# Add a Google Chat bot programmatically

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-chat

I have a web application for organizations. I would like to allow users to add an existing Google Chat bot to their Google Chat workspace programmatically - example workflow: Jack visits mywebsite.com, presses button 'Add site bot' and the bot gets added to their Google Chat where the bot can asynchronously message the user.

Is this functionality possible at the moment or does the user have to connect the bot manually through the Google Chat interface?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: I don't think there is a direct link for that, but why not re-directing to https://chat.google.com/botcatalog/details/id-of-the-bot?

Comment: Thanks @Jescanellas, that's the way I am going to try and approach it. I was just curious if I could do it directly, so I can link/sync the website account with the google chat api account instantly instead of waiting for the ADDED TO SPACE event.